# Setting the opacity of an element through JQuery's css method removes background-image

Tags: jquery, css, opacity

I have a background-image set on an element. When I change the element's opacity through JQuery using the css method on hover, the background-image disappears! What gives? Here the sample on codepen:

CSS

```
li{
    background-image:url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-checkmark-circled-32.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

li img{
    z-index:-1;
    position:relative;
}
```

JQuery

```
$("li").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("opacity", 0.8);
}
)
```

http://codepen.io/rimager/pen/LAfJy/

Comment: Works in opera 12 and in 36.0.1985.143 m , windows 8.1

Comment: It seems weird, I have the same issue in Chrome 36 on Win7 32bit. The background image will disappear even by using `opacity: 0.99`.

Comment: Also working here in Chrome.  Question I have is, do you want the whole li to lose opacity, or just dim the image?

Comment: Do you mean the checkmark icon disappears? Or the image behind disappears?

Comment: @BrianBennett The checkmark which is the only background image in the demo.

Comment: Oh, good point. Should have looked closer...

Comment: The checkmark icon disappears. The image does not.

Comment: Also it seems unrelated to the JQuery. If I use li:hover the same thing happens.

Comment: It is related to the browser. It seems that, when changing the opacity, the image is rendered again in front of everything. See this demo with the background repeated, you could see that the background is still there: http://jsfiddle.net/a3oqfed4/ But no idea why this happen. (OS X 10.9, Safari 7.0.5 also happens)

Comment: OK in IE11 - looks very nice.

Comment: Why not you use css's :hover pseudo cladd it is better to use css if its possible everywhere.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was just testing JQuery. The CSS :hover has the same problem though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example using your code with a little modification...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jsicb[1](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jsicb)

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7014/6741363919_3e0580543e_q.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Claude Monet - Bordighera  - 1883"></li>
  <li><img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2366/2555929697_00046ed797_q.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Claude Monet - Orchard in Bloom"></li>
  <li><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3427/3750216840_feefcd6e17_q.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Monet, &quot;Impression, Sunrise&quot;"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{
  float:left;
  margin:20px;

  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}
li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 32px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  margin-left: -16px;
background:url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-checkmark-circled-32.png) no-repeat center center transparent;  

}

li img{
  z-index:-1;
  position:relative;
}

/*
li:hover{
  opacity:0.8;
}
*/
```

Now if you want to apply the same opacity option using the hover state without using javascript or jquery, just let me know and I will post the modified source right here.

Comment: Thank you Allan. I can see how using the ::after pseudo-element fixes my problem. I still don't understand very well though why the opacity removed the background-image. I guess it's just one of those CSS quirks to remember?

Comment: If you want a working example without Jquery or javascript, just let me know, that way you will be able to handle the opacity using css only, even with transition fx

Answer (score 0):

Here's another working example:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li id="item1"><img id="img1" src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7014/6741363919_3e0580543e_q.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Claude Monet - Bordighera  - 1883"></li>
  <li id="item2"><img id="img2" src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2366/2555929697_00046ed797_q.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Claude Monet - Orchard in Bloom"></li>
  <li id="item3"><img id="img3" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3427/3750216840_feefcd6e17_q.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="Monet, &quot;Impression, Sunrise&quot;"></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$("#item1").hover(function(){


 $("#img1").css("opacity", 0.8);
  },
  function(){
  $("#img1").css("opacity", 1);
  }
)
$("#item2").hover(function(){
  $("#img2").css("opacity", 0.8);
  },
  function(){
  $("#img2").css("opacity", 1);
  }
)
$("#item3").hover(function(){
  $("#img3").css("opacity", 0.8);
  },
  function(){
  $("#img3").css("opacity", 1);
  }
)
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9r1rb627/)**

Comment: Thank you Syed. That is another good solution. Do you know why I am having that problem in the first place though?

Comment: You were setting the opacity of `li` while you only wanted the background image to have that effect. Assign an ID to image of `li` and then use `opacity` on that. as in example code.